# android app is stopped running

Tags: android

I'm learning android and this app is my one of my first app but I could not run it , either on emulator or on my own Galaxy 2 ! it says that the app is stopped unexpectedly.
the error on the log is " no command output when running : 'am start

I used platform 2.2 and I run the code on my MAC

notice that I searched a lot and tested many solution already without any help . like Clear the project , start emulator from AVD with wipe user data clicked , creating new project and copy it on that .

any ideas?

```
public class TutorialOne extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{
TextView textOut;
EditText textIn;
RadioGroup gravityG, styleG;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChange);
    textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
    gravityG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgGravity);
    gravityG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    styleG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgStyle);
    styleG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Button gen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGenerate);

    gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textOut.setText(textIn.getText());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch (checkedId){
    case R.id.rbLeft:
        textOut.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        break;
    case R.id.rbCenter:
        textOut.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        break;
    case R.id.rbRight:
        textOut.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        break;
    case R.id.rbNormal:
    textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL),Typeface.NORMAL);
    break;
    case R.id.rbItalic:
        textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC),Typeface.ITALIC);
        break;
    case R.id.rbBold:
        textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD),Typeface.BOLD);
        break;

    }
}
}
```

here is my manifest , I dont see anything wrong:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Android2Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

these are the error in log cat:

> 03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.newboston.aida.android2/com.newboston.aida.android2.Android2Activity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.newboston.aida.android2.Android2Activity in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.newboston.aida.android2-2.apk]
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 03-31
>   23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-31
>   23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 03-31 23:39:28.580:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) 03-31
>   23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-31
>   23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 03-31 23:39:28.580:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665) 03-31
>   23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-31 23:39:28.580:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12259): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.newboston.aida.android2.Android2Activity in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.newboston.aida.android2-2.apk]
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551) 03-31
>   23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 03-31
>   23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
>   03-31 23:39:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(12259):  ... 11 more

Comment: The "error on the log" that you cite is not your error. You will find a Java stack trace in LogCat that is your error. "the code also dont have problem cause I get that from a tutorial ." -- it would appear to "have problem", since you are getting an error.

Comment: there are a lot of errors there in LOgCat like E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)

Comment: Check whether you have registered your activity in the Manifest file.

Comment: I will assume you are using Eclipse. In our logcat, When your app force closes, there will be a big block of words that are colored red. Within that block, probably in a few places, it will have your application's package name `com.example.awesomeapp`, and it will also likely contain your `Activity`s name, possibly like: `com.example.awesomeapp.AwesomeActivity`. (just clarifying so you get the right log). You should edit your question and post the entirety of THAT piece of logcat in the question. Then we can pinpoint what the problem is.

Comment: there are a lot of errors there in log cat like java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.newboston.aida.android2/com.newboston.aida.android2.Android2Activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.newboston.aida.android2.Android2Activity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.newboston.aida.android2-2.apk]

Comment: Please post your complete manifest.  Also try using the full class name for Android2Activity instead of .Android2Activity and also post your main layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the your activity name needs to match what is found in your manifest.

Your activity name is "TutorialOne"but in your manifest the activity name is ".Android2Activity".

I think that is why the LogCat says could not instantiate the activity.

If you are new to Android I suggest beginning a New Project as this will take care of these details for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity name is "TutorialOne" but in your manifest the activity name is ".Android2Activity". so just replace ".Android2Activity" with "TutorialOne" in your manifeast file. 
 Also it would be better if you can paste your xml file.